# How to analyze a 4x2 design with an additional control condition?

Tags: anova, control-group

I have a somewhat unusual study setup, for which I'm not sure how to analyze it properly. Basically, I have a 4x2 factorial design which assigns users to a condition A (4 levels) and at the same time B (2 levels). However, I also have a control group in which participants get neither A nor B - so no experimental condition at all, just a baseline.

If it were just the 4x2 factorial design, I could run a two-way ANOVA. However, this would leave out the control condition. Another way might be to group the 4x2 together, so I come out with 8 + 1 conditions and then perform a simple one-way ANOVA. However, this would not account for possible interaction effects between A and B if I'm not mistaken.

What's the best way to approach this? I'm happy for any guidance and direction.

Comment: A linear model.

Comment: @user2974951 Could you elaborate on your answer a bit more? Why do you think a linear model is the best option in this case?

Comment: It's used for post-hoc contrasts, which is what you want. You would first do an ANOVA on the now 9 new levels, and then do custom contrasts with a linear model. See https://rcompanion.org/rcompanion/h_01.html for more info.